# Why is this string comparison not working?

Tags: swift-playground

I have defined a function in swift that will take two strings as parameters and return true if they are the same:

```
func compareString(f_string:String,S_string:String)->Bool{
   if f_string == S_string{
      return true
   }
}
```

*Why does it show an error message?*

Comment: Please show the error message.

Answer (score 2):

your function is supposed to return a boolean value everytime, but it returns only when the strings are equal. add a return false statement after if and it should work.

```
func compareString(f_string:String,S_string:String)->Bool{
   if f_string == S_string{
      return true
   }
return false
}
```

Comment: This can also be simplified as `return f_string == S_string` in this simple case.

Comment: Yes, it can be...I just wanted to make him understand the problem.